# Manipulate HTML in custom Drupal menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a custom menu in Drupal, where I want to apply bootstrap classes to. The menu doesn't sit at the normal positions, however. It's placed in a panel that I created with the panels modules.

I tied so many different things that I found, like this tutorial:
http://www.nybergtechnology.com/blog/2013/11/11/druapl-7-dropdown-menu-using-twitter-bootstrap

However, using something like this

```
function mytheme_menu_link( array $variables ) {
    return '<li class="my-class">something</li>';
}
```

doesn't change anything in any of my menus. This doesn't seem to be the right approach. Do you have any idea how I can manipulate the html of custom menus?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: Please read documentation and good practice about theming : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/menu-theming

Comment: And https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/advanced-menu-theming-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

You can return the html from a menu as a string. Eg: return `"<div class=''>Text</div>"`